# Problem connecting to the database with a redbean php

Tags: php, mysql, database, localhost, redbean

I use open server with RedBean PHP, after connecting to the database. When I try to create a table, I have an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'Could not connect to database (sots).' in C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php:1011 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php(735): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->connect() #1 C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php(1035): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->runQuery('show tables', Array) #2 C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php(1056): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetAll('show tables', Array) #3 C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php(4183): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetCol('show tables', Array) #4 C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php(6652): RedBeanPHP\Adapter\DBAdapter->getCol('show tables') #5 C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php(5857): RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\MySQL->getTables() #6 C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php(8912): RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\AQueryWriter->tableExists('acounts') #7 C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php(9014): Re in C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php on line 1011

*in this script I connect redbean and to the database:*

> ```
> <?php
> require "rb.php";   
>
> R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sots',
>         'mysql ', 'mysql' );
>  ?>
> ```

*when you click on the button from the form it is executed:*

> 

```
<?php session_start(); require_once "db.php";
> 
> $data=$_POST; if (isset($data['do_regis'])) {
>     $user= R::dispense('acounts');
>     $user->login=$data['login'];
>     R::store($user);
>     $dir=$data['login'];
>     if (is_dir($dir)==false) {
>       mkdir('Accounts/'.$dir);
>       mkdir('Accounts/'.$dir.'/Postes');
>       mkdir('Accounts/'.$dir.'/Photos');
>     }
> 
> }
> ?>
```

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Comment: Imagine yourself in our shoes. Someone tells us that they got an error, but they show us no code or any other crucial details. It is too difficult for us to guess what could be the issue here.

Comment: sorry i have already completed my question